# Getting warning in iPhone: NSString may not respond to '-JSONValue'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, json, ios4, ios-4.2

In my iPhone app, I am making an access to the webserver to fetch the data.

Here I am using JSON to retrieve the data from database.

I get a warning that says:

> NSString may not respond to '-JSONValue'

How to resolve it?

Comment: Worth having a look at [this page](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/issues/detail?id=22) for additional tips.

Comment: See my response in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379859/instance-method-jsonvaluenot-found-return-type-defaults-to-id/19300534#19300534

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this `#import "JSON.h"` at the top of your `.m` or `.h` file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add [JSON Library](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to your project and import it

```
#import "JSON/JSON.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just miss the include to your JSON library