# Instance method '-jsonValue'not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got problem in following statement.

```
 NSArray *feedsData = [strFeedsResponse JSONValue];
```

Comment: What is the type of `strFeedsResponse`? Improve your question little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a webservice, then give  the URL for that.

try this way...

```
NSArray* latestentry = (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume `strFeedsResponse` is an instance of `NSString`. There is no such method as `JSONValue` in `NSString`. You need NSString **category** and add the `JSONValue` method there.

You can use for example **SBJson** library https://github.com/stig/json-framework/, which contains NSString+SBJson.h header, which adds the `JSONValue` method for NSString.

This header must be than imported in the source file where you want to use the `JSONValue` method:

```
#import NSString+SBJSON.h
```

More about categories for example here: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is happening:

1. strFeedsResponse is not ACTUALLY an instance of an NSString. Maybe it is null or it has been initiated with an incorrect value. You can add a breakpoint to your code to check the value that is stored in strFeedsResponse before you call JSONValue on it.
2. You have not correctly imported the JSON framework that you are using into your class. You need to add the JSON header to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps future searchers on this error...

The reason for the error is that the current version of SBJson seems to not contain the NSString category "NSString+SBJSON.h" referred to by an earlier poster. So, you could easily write your own, or just use the SBJsonParser class directly ("address" is just an NSString containing something like "24 Elm Street, Yourtown, New Mexico"):

```
NSString     *esc_addr       = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString     *req            = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
NSString     *response       = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
SBJsonParser *parser         = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *googleResponse = [parser objectWithString:response];
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *feedsData = [[strFeedsResponse JSONValue] mutableCopy];
```

Use this Line, it will be useful to you..

Comment: Or Use this line also  NSArray *feedsData = (NSArray *)[strFeedsResponse JSONValue];

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when method not found.Here it comes because **JSONValue** function is not found.
Please make sure you have included json header files where you calling this function.