# Locate address in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, geocoding

I tried to load an address in MKMapView , for that I used the following code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self getLocationFromAddressString:@"321 Iowa St, Fallbrook, CA 92028, United States US"];
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

region.span = span;
region.center = location;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Below is the code for getting location for the given address

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr 
{
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                    [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double lat = 0.0;
double lon = 0.0;

if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    lon = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = lat;
location.longitude = lon;

return location;
}
```

But it returns,

`Address, 321 Iowa St, Fallbrook, CA 92028, United States US not found: Error 610`

why I got this error?

Comment: This type of same issue create with me..in google map some city/area not found in map..and also some latitude and longitude value does not get full information of co-ordinate ...for more info follow my Question ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128700/get-specific-value-between-javascript-function-by-nsregularexpression

Comment: Have a look at my response to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379859/instance-method-jsonvaluenot-found-return-type-defaults-to-id/19300534#19300534

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ::

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
   double latitude = 0.0;
   double longitude = 0.0;

   NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

   NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

   NSDictionary    *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];   // get the results dictionary
   NSDictionary   *geometryDict = [resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];   // geometry dictionary within the  results dictionary
   NSDictionary   *locationDict = [geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];   // location dictionary within the geometry dictionary

   NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"];
   NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

   NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"];
   NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

   CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
   location.latitude = [latString doubleValue];// latitude;
   location.longitude = [lngString doubleValue]; //longitude;

   return location;
}
```

I found same issue earlier.

May be there is an issue regarding Google API Service.

Hopefully, it'll be htlp to you.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason this example works, v/s the one from the question, is that this one uses the correct address and format for addressing the geocoding api

Comment: nice help, but I receive an error`Automatic Reference Counting Issue: No known instance method for selector 'JSONValue'`, how to solve this

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting issue is regarding memory issue. If you are using ARC then no need to alloc & release variables.

Comment: it says "No known instance method for selector 'JSONValue'

Comment: dis you import "JSON" files ?

Comment: In line :: NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue]; -> we are getting response in JSON format.

Comment: thank u very much, ur code working well, I tried it in another non arc project. now Iam trying to disable the arc for json files in my project to acheive this

Comment: @NAZIK: Pleasure to help you.. Enjoy Coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?hl=fr#GGeoStatusCode)

> G_GEO_BAD_KEY
>   = 610    The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given.

Answer (score 1):

from what i can tell from google's [geocoding api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

is that you are calling their api the wrong way.
A call to their api should look like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=321%20Iowa%20St,%20Fallbrook,%20CA%2092028,%20United%20States%20US
```